# Force site links to use localhost

Tags: localhost

I do hope someone can help please.

Ive downloaded a site from my server and installed MAMP (Free Version) on OSX sonoma.
After a lot of faffing I've got the site up and running but it only loads the home (index.php) page. If I click any of the links it says 'The requested URL was not found on this server.'
I can edit the URL to correct this to get other pages, but I need to log in to the back-end to fix a problem and it wont let me even though I have the correct login details.
The site is built using concrete cms.

Thanks in advance.

Went to site login page (e.g. http://localhost/site/index.php/login
completed the login details and clicked login
ERROR The requested URL was not found on this server.

Comment: I've actually figured this out by myself!
I installed the same core version as a new blank dummy site, then copied over all the config files concrete/config, then compared each file with the current ones and altered the code accordingly until it worked.

Pat myself on the back as I'm just a designer  not a coder.